# How can I create a bunch of images overlaying two images quickly?

Tags: c++, image, performance, imagemagick, cimg

I'm trying with ImageMagick GraphicsMagick and CImg but it takes 10 minutes to complete 10,000 images.

**I need to do this in 3 minutes.**

How I could do this task faster?

This is my code:

```
#define cimg_use_png
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cimg_library;
int main() {
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
   CImg<unsigned char> gradient("gradient.png");
   CImg<unsigned char> overlay("overlay.png");
   gradient.draw_image(80,150,overlay);
   gradient.save_png("result.png");

}
}
```

How I could do this faster using other libraries or another language? I have a 2 Ghz processor and 4 GB of RAM.

Please Help Me

Comment: Try using multiple threads.  One thread reads the images into a buffer.  Thread 2 performs the overlays to a new buffer.  Thread 3 writes the overlay images to the file.  Adjust buffer sizes to optimize for speed.

Comment: Based on the docs (http://cimg.eu/CImg_reference.pdf), it appears that CImg can employ OpenMP, a parallel programming library. Might want to look into that.

Comment: Save your gradient to MPC (memory mapped format) once. Then reading back for use in overlaying the same gradient will be much faster. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#mpc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slowest part is the decoding & encoding of the PNG i/o operations. If we can move the *read* operations outside of the for loop, and clone the image *data* with the [copy constructor](http://cimg.eu/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#aff97beaa34b9061351711dcdaed85c58), then we should be able to improve the speed under 3 minutes.

```cpp
#define cimg_use_png
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cimg_library;

int main() {
    CImg<unsigned char> parent_gradient("gradient.png");
    CImg<unsigned char> parent_overlay("overlay.png");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
        CImg<unsigned char> gradient(parent_gradient);
        CImg<unsigned char> overlay(parent_overlay);
        gradient.draw_image(80,150,overlay);
        gradient.save_png("result.png");
    }
}
```

We can go farther by implementing [OpenMP](https://openmp.llvm.org) to distribute the work load across the CPU threads. On my mac, this drops the 10000 iterations under 20 secs.

```cpp
#define cimg_use_png
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cimg_library;

int main() {
    CImg<unsigned char> parent_gradient("gradient.png");
    CImg<unsigned char> parent_overlay("overlay.png");
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
        CImg<unsigned char> gradient(parent_gradient);
        CImg<unsigned char> overlay(parent_overlay);
        gradient.draw_image(80,150,overlay);
        gradient.save_png("result.png");
    }
}
```